# How can I log changes like "ALTER table [...] ADD column" to my PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger, audit

I would like to log when a column was added to my table. I already found an overview (`information_schema.columns`). However, the time is missing here, even deleted columns are not displayed. I am using PostgreSQL 8.4.4 and I could update to 9.6.5

My idea was a trigger on `information_schema.columns`, but that doesn't work because it's not a table.

Comment: Why upgrade to "only" 9.6 in 2019? Why not upgrade to the current version? (11 - soon to be 12) And if you are really restricted to 9.6 for some reason, you need at least go for 9.6.15 which is the latest version in the 9.6 branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With newer versions of postgres, you can use [event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/event-triggers.html).  It doesn't look like you can get info on the actual column that was added, unless you write the function in C to parse the pg_ddl_command type, but you can get info on the table affected, who did it, and when:

```
CREATE TABLE alter_table_log (
  id bigserial primary key,
  tstamp timestamp with time zone default now(),
  table_id regclass,
  altered_by regrole
);

GRANT insert, select on table alter_table_log to public;
GRANT usage on alter_table_log_id_seq to public;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_alter_trig() 
RETURNS event_trigger 
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
  BEGIN
        INSERT INTO alter_table_log(table_id, altered_by)
        select obj.objid::regclass, current_user::regrole
        FROM (select * from pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()) as obj;
  END
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER log_alter_trig
  ON ddl_command_end
  WHEN TAG IN ('ALTER TABLE')
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_alter_trig();

create table test (a text);
alter table test add column b text;
select * from alter_table_log;

 id |            tstamp             | table_id | altered_by
----+-------------------------------+----------+------------
  1 | 2019-09-03 13:21:36.361964+00 | test     | postgres
```

You won't be able to do this in 8.4.  I would recommend updating to 11.  9.6 won't buy you much time before that is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to take advantage of [Postgres Reporting and Logging tools](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html):

Basically you would need to set the `log_statement` paprameter to (at least) `'ddl'`:

> `ddl` logs all data definition statements, such as `CREATE`, `ALTER`, and `DROP` statements

Then you should be able to grep expressions like `"alter table <mytable> add column"` in the server logs.

PS:

- you need to [reload the configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html) for the changes to take effect
- if *lots of* DDL operations happen in your database, this setting might generate a lot of logs, making this solution kind of an overkill

Comment: First of all, thank you. It works. But it's not really what I'm looking for. The loggin is already running on (`log_destination = 'stderr'`) and I can't just set it to (`'csvlog'`) for a better overview because I'm using external software. 

Now I would have to parse the logfile regularly and write it to the database. 

Is there perhaps a more elegant solution that saves the data directly formatted? Can I set the (`log_destination to 'stderr' and 'csvlog'`) and save only the (`log_statement = 'ddl' in 'csvlog'`)?

Comment: @Andreas; well you can set multiple logging destination with an expression like: `log_destination('stderr,csvlog')`. However I don’t think that it is possible to have different login settings per destination.